# Asymptotic behaviour of Bessel function of the second kind with a negative order

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions

Is there any result on the asymptotic behaviour of Bessel function of the second kind with a negative order? What I have found is the behaviour when the order $Re(\nu)>0$. For example, it is shown in pp. 360 in [1] that

$$Y_v(z)\approx -(1/\pi)\Gamma(\nu)(\frac12 z)^{-\nu}, Re(\nu)>0.$$

What is the behaviour when $Re(\nu)<0$? Thanks very much.

[1] ABRAMOWITZ M, STEGUN I A 1972. Handbook Of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables [M]. Dover Publications; New York.

Answer (score 3):

You find the general asymptotic behavior [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms). For the case where the order is not an negative integer, we have (valid for small $z$)
$$ Y_\alpha(z) \sim-\dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\pi} \left( \dfrac{2}{z} \right)^\alpha + \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)} \left(\dfrac{z}{2} \right)^\alpha \cot(\alpha \pi)  \,.$$
For $\alpha>0$, the first term dominates and you obtain the result, you have quoted in the question.

For $\alpha<0$, the second term dominates, and we have
$$Y_\alpha(z) \sim \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)} \left(\dfrac{z}{2} \right)^\alpha \cot(\alpha \pi).$$

If $\alpha = -n$ is a negative integer, we have instead
$$ Y_{-n}(z) \sim -\dfrac{(-1)^{n}\Gamma(n)}{\pi} \left( \dfrac{2}{z} \right)^{n}\,.$$

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks a lot.